# Webpack img(image) path error

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, path

I'm using webpack in my project, there are two images in my project.

the first image path is: /**build**/img/1.png  (The following is called A)
the second image path is /**build**/img/2.png, (The following is called B)

The two pictures have the same path. but, the A can be displayed on the page, B can not.

my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
// var assetsPluginInstance = new AssetsPlugin();
// var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var remotePath = "./__build__/";
fs.readdir(remotePath, function (err, files) {
    if (!err) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var filesName = files[i];
            if (filesName.indexOf("chunk.js") > 1) {
                fs.unlink('./__build__/' + filesName);
            }
        }
    }
});


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: "./web_app/index.js"
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/__build__',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: (new Date()).getTime() + '[id].chunk.js',
        publicPath: '/__build__/'
    },

    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        proxy: {
            '*': {
                changeOrigin: true,
                //target: 'xxx',
                target: 'xxx',
                secure: false
            }
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            },
        }),

        // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./__build__/dll/lib-manifest.json')
        }),

        new AssetsPlugin({
            filename: '__build__/webpack.assets.js',
            processOutput: function (assets) {
                return 'window.WEBPACK_ASSETS = ' + JSON.stringify(assets);
            }
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),

        // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        //     mangle: {
        //         except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require']
        //     },
        //     compress: {
        //         warnings: false,
        //     },
        //     output: {
        //         comments: false,
        //     },
        // }),

        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                moment: "moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"
            }
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                // loaders: ['babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-0'],
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    plugins: ["transform-object-assign", "add-module-exports"],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
                },
                include: path.join(__dirname, '.')
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            }, {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: 'style!css!less'
            }, {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|svg|ttf|woff2|gif|appcache)(\?|$)/,
                exclude: /^node_modules$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                exclude: /^node_modules$/,
                loader: 'url?name=[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Jwg.jpg)

[Image sequence: React code, project directory, dev Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFx1M.jpg)

I've merged several images, because stackoverflow rules that I can only publish two links

Comment: Can you please update your post with the code in which you attempt to load these images?

Comment: After I put two images in the folder ( __build__/img ), I started it directly ( npm start ), so, do you mean the start-up interface ?

Comment: I mean the React file where you are actually importing the image to render it to the DOM.

Comment: hello, I modified the question.